# How does logging off a user session in Windows manage to kill "unkillable" processes?

Tags: windows, debugging, process

Related to [a question I asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40257161/svn-exe-process-showing-as-suspended-in-process-explorer-unable-to-kill) -- I have a process that I launched which is in a "suspended" state. I cannot kill or resume this process through any of the normal means (process explorer, task manager, WinDbg).

Logging-out of my session DOES kill this process though. How? What mechanism is the OS using when I log out that is somehow different to what Process Explorer is trying to do?

Edit: To clarify - I am assuming that Process Explorer is calling the TerminateProcess API function when it tries to kill a process. Something in the process state is stopping this from working though. Logging out obviously invokes some different behaviour and Windows ignores whatever was blocking TerminateProcess, and kills the process due to my session ending.

As a user, is there any different way to try and terminate a process other than calling the TerminateProcess API?

Comment: This *probably* isn't anything that Windows is doing on purpose.  My guess is that whatever is causing the process to get stuck (which must be in kernel mode, perhaps faulty anti-virus software or a faulty device driver) just happens to correct itself under the right circumstances, and logging off causes that to happen.  IOW, it's probably just a coincidence that logging off fixes the problem.

Comment: On the other hand, it is plausible that when the window station is deleted (for example) the kernel uses ZwTerminateProcess to kill any remaining processes and perhaps issuing the call from kernel mode bypasses whatever is jamming up the original process.  There's no easy way to test this theory though.  In any case, you're probably better off solving the original problem rather than trying to work around it - this is *not* normal behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Process Explorer can't kill a process itself; it can only ask the OS to do so. The OS itself doesn't have to play by its own rules.

Remember, it's the OS itself which defines what a process is. It might very well define a process as part of a logon session. This would imply that if you clean up the whole session then you don't need to clean up individual processes. Just like you don't need to bother with `CloseHandle` before `ExitProcess` either.